# Not able to select VNet gateway when creating local network gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm having problem when creating connection on Local network gateway.

when I'm creating connection the Vnet gateway is selectable but when i select it the Azure did not populate or actually select the gateway not sure why. is there any subscript do i needed or my vnet gateway is created incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same scenario in my environment wherein I tried with the Local network gateway to make connection with the Virtual network  gateway,  and it is successfully done. Please find the below snapshots for your reference.***

I have created a Virtual network, a Virtual network gateway, a local network gateway in the same location and assigned the local network gateway a different virtual network subnet other than the one created earlier and assigned the virtual network gateway, the original one.

***Vnet:***

[image]

***Virtual network gateway:***
[image]

***Local Network gateway:***
[image]

The process is you need to add your connection in Virtual network gateway by below process:

[image]

When I add connection in virtual network gateway it created and reflected in local network gateway.

[image]

Reference:
[Tutorial - Connect an on-premises network and a virtual network: S2S VPN: Azure portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal)